# Trigger SQL Server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, postgresql, trigger

Eu tenho essa *trigger* em `Postgresql` e estou com dificuldades para transforma-lá em `SQL Server`.

```
-- Trigger --
CREATE TRIGGER livro_original
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON tabela
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insere_valor_original();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insere_valor_original()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF (new.es_original <= 0 OR new.es_original is null) THEN
        new.es_original = new.id_codigo;
    END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Estou tentando desta forma:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_EXEMPLO ON tabela FOR INSERT AS 
BEGIN 
  update inserted 
  set INSERTED.es_ORIGINAL = INSERTED.ID_CODIGO 
  where INSERTED.ID_CODIGO = INSERTED.ID_CODIGO 
END
```

Porém recebo este erro:

> As tabelas lógicas INSERTED e DELETED não podem ser atualizadas

Comment: Richard, não há "BEFORE INSERT" no SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

O erro é que está tentando atualizar as tabelas que o *sql-server* utiliza para controle de ações no *banco*, o que não é permitido; estas tabelas devem ser usadas apenas para consulta.

> *Para entendimento da lógica:*
>
> - Se a *trigger* for de **INSERT**, a `INSERTED` terá registros e a `DELETED` ficará vazia
> - Se a *trigger* for de **DELETE**, a `INSERTED` ficará vazia e a `DELETED` terá registros
> - Se a *trigger* for de **UPDATE**, a `INSERTED` e a `DELETED` terão registros

Entendido isso, você deverá utilizar estas tabelas para entender o que será atualizado na *sua* tabela (`tabela`):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_EXEMPLO ON tabela FOR INSERT AS 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE tabela
  SET tabela.es_ORIGINAL = INSERTED.ID_CODIGO 
  WHERE tabela.ID_CODIGO = INSERTED.ID_CODIGO 
END
```

---

Porém, se me permite, sugiro que a "atualização" seja feita na própria ação de inserir. Pela pergunta, você dará um `update` na tabela `tabela` após um `insert` na tabela `tabela`, o que aparentemente não faz sentido...